# jQuery Mobile Grid with auto-resizing images

Tags: image, jquery-mobile, grid, resize

I have this grid:

```html
<div class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <div class="ui-bar"> <a href="xxx.htm">
        <img alt="alt..." src="image.jpg" />
        </a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <div class="ui-bar"> <a href="xxx.htm">
        <img alt="alt..." src="image.jpg" />
        </a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-c">
        <div class="ui-bar"> <a href="xxx.htm">
        <img alt="alt..." src="image.jpg" />
        </a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <div class="ui-bar"> <a href="xxx.htm">
        <img alt="alt..." src="image.jpg" />
        </a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <div class="ui-bar"> <a href="xxx.htm">
        <img alt="alt..." src="image.jpg" />
        </a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-c">
        <div class="ui-bar"> <a href="xxx.htm">
        <img alt="alt..." src="image.jpg" />
        </a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But my images (180X80px) display "*cropped*" on the iPhone screen (320px width).

**How can I auto resize them?**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can set the CSS of your images to automatically take-up all the horizontal space available on the screen:

```
<style>
.ui-grid-b img {
    width  : 100%;
    height : auto;
}
</style>
```

This will set each image to completely fill its parent element (`<div class="ui-bar">`) horizontally while maintaining its aspect ratio.

Comment: I'd like to point out when using `width`, images will scale up or down to fill the container. If you were to use `max-width` instead, small images would not be scaled up, which may be desirable for some people.

Comment: I'm setting my image width to 100% and height to auto in my phonegap/jquery mobile/iphone application, but the image still looks cut off

Comment: @farjam Are you using a `viewport` meta tag? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448465/jquery-mobile-device-scaling/6457261#6457261

Comment: Yes, here is the full `viewport`: `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />`

Answer (score 0):

I have somthing similar and I had the same issue.
I fixed it by removing some divs ...

Try this:

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">

    <a href="xxx.htm">
    <img alt="alt..." src="image.jpg" />
    </a>

    <a href="xxx.htm">
    <img alt="alt..." src="image.jpg" />
    </a>

</div>
```

It works im my case (Tested on iPhone Simulator, Iphone 4, Android Emulator)

Header:

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
   .ui-grid-b img {
       width  : 100%;
       height : auto;
   }
```