# Windows Phone 7 jQuery mobile horizontal scrolling failure

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, horizontal-scrolling

I work with jQuery mobile on Windows Phone 7. I have a header and content. My problem is, that the content has a width  of 100% what is great, but the headers with is more than 100% because I can scroll the Webbrowser and the header has a black bar on the right. That explained me that it is bigger. But I don't know what I have to change to make it without scrolling.

Thanx
newone

Comment: Are you using a webbrowser control, or something like PhoneGap to do the JQuery mobile stuff?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Mobile Device Scaling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448465/jquery-mobile-device-scaling)

Answer (score 1):

It may be a viewport issue.  In your `<Head>` tag, try adding this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

If that works, do a search on "meta viewport" to get details on how to further control the users' experience.