# iOS 8.3 - Meta viewport with fixed width results in weird content scaling on orientation change

Tags: html, ios, mobile, orientation, viewport

After upgrading my iOS devices to iOS 8.3 I noticed some weird behavior with the meta viewport.
If I set the viewport with fixed width(a number such as 640, other than device-width) and rotate my device while I am on a webpage, the whole content will get smaller and eventually the browser will crash.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
```

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Similar situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29601279/ios-8-3-meta-viewport-initial-scale-under-1-0-results-in-weird-content-scaling

Comment: `minimum-scale=1.0` is telling the browser that we don’t ever want the page to be zoomed out past 100% ? `<meta name="viewport" content="width= 640,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0" />`  Let me know the result.