# iOS 8.3 web app crashes on orientation change if viewport width meta tag is set to fixed value

Tags: ios, html, mobile-safari, iphone-web-app, ios8.3

When running our web-app in **full-screen mode** on **iOS 8.3**, Safari **crashes** when  changing the **orientation of the phone a couple of times (2-5 times)**.

To get to the full-screen mode we used the *Add to home screen* feature of Safari, and started app by tapping on home screen icon of the web app.

The crashes only happen in full-screen mode - when the web-app is started by navigating to it's URL, Safari doesn't crash when changing the orientation.

This clearly seems to be a **bug introduced by Apple on iOS 8.3**. We can see that everything works fine on iOS 8.2.

The question is just if anybody knows a workaround or when this will be fixed?

We've now seen this already happening for all kinds different web app - would be a shame if Apple doesn't provide a fix for this issue soon.

Here is the code to reproduce. To make it crash, just run it from the home screen, turn the phone a couple of times and voilà...

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=640, user-scalable=no">
  </head>
  <body>
    content
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

PS: I'm aware that similar questions have already been asked (see links) but none of the answers provides a valid solution for us as we definitely can't get rid of the *width=640, user-scalable=no* viewport meta tag.

Comment: This seems to be the same problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737908/ios-8-3-meta-viewport-with-fixed-width-results-in-weird-content-scaling-on-ori/30490192#30490192